# $H\in\mathcal L \left({V}\right)$ exists such the range of $H$ is contained in $U$ and $H(u)=T(u)$ for all $u\in U$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose U$\subset$V is an $T$-invariant subspace and $V$ is finite dimensional. Prove that a linear transformation $H\in\mathcal L \left({V}\right)$ exists such the range of $H$ is contained in $U$ and $H(u)=T(u)$ for all $u\in U$

My Attempt:

Range is defined as: For $T$ a function from $V$ to $W$,the range of $T$ is the subset of $W$ consisting of those vectors that are of the form $Tv$ for some $v\in V$ :

$\mathcal L \left({V}\right)$ is a linear map from a vector space to itself. 
 $\mathcal L \left({V}\right)$= 
 $\mathcal L \left({V,V}\right)$

A linear map is additive and homogenous.

$T$-invariant is defined as: If $T\in \left({V}\right)R$ then a subspace $U$ of $V$ is called invariant under $T$ if $u\in U$ implies $Tu\in U$

Not sure how to put this all together to proove this problem.

Comment: $\;\mathcal L(V)\;$ is *not* a map but rather the vector space of all linear maps from $\;V\;$ to itself or endomorphisms.

Comment: If $\;U\;$ is a proper subspaceo f $\;V\;$ , then $\;H\;$  a linear map on $\;V\;$ cannot be invertible **and also**  that its range is contained in $\;U\;$ .

Comment: how should I start? Any hints?

Comment: Did you read what I wrote above? The information of your question makes no sense.

Comment: I edited the question. There was a typo

Comment: Find a complementary subspace of $U$ in $V$, i.e. a subspace $W$ with $U\cap W = \{0\}$ and $V = U + W$.

Comment: What if I suppose T:H->H is invertable and prove it by contradiction?